# Find Maximum Coordinate Point where Pixel value is 1 on x-axis, in 2-D image (Binary) (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I'm using Matlab and I have a 2-D Array (image), like this

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

in the following array, I want to get very first position (with respect to X-axis)  where X and Y have value "1" and very last position (with respect to X-axis) where X and Y have value "1".

Does anyone know the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way using `any` and `find`. I assume that your image is called `image`

```
minimumX = find(any(image,1),1,'first')
maximumX = find(any(image,1),1,'last')
```

An alternative way is to use `BoundingBox` from `regionprops`:

```
stats = regionprops(image,'BoundingBox');

minimumX = stats.BoundingBox(1);
maximumX = sum(stats.BoundingBox([1 3]));
```

Comment: @LuisMendo: `any` creates a row vector. Consequently, the linear index returned by `find` indicates the column of minimum/maximum X, respectively.

Comment: That gives me a single number. I have interpreted the OP question in a different way: that a vector result is needed

Comment: @LuisMendo: Oh, now I understand! Yeah, I was interpreting the question as the minimum/maximum x of the whole shape.

Comment: @Jonas!! Thank you for helping.. I got, your solution works..
Thanks again

Comment: @muaaz: I'm glad the solution was helpful. Please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with [`max`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/max.html), exploting the facts that

> [Y,I] = MAX(X,[],DIM) operates along the dimension DIM.

and that

> If the values [...] contain more than one maximal element, the index of the first one is returned.

Let `img` denote your 2D array. I'm assuming your x-axis is the row index. Otherwise change `,2` to `,1` (three times) and `fliplr` to `flipud` (once).

```
[valid, first] = max(img,[],2);
first(~valid) = NaN;
[~, last] = max(fliplr(img),[],2);
last = size(img,2)-last+1;
last(~valid) = NaN;
```

In your example:

```
first =
   NaN
   NaN
     5
     3
     4
     5
     8
   NaN
   NaN

last =
   NaN
   NaN
     9
    10
    11
    10
     8
   NaN
   NaN
```